# Nanoscroller.js - text overflowing but not scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using Nanoscroller (http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/) to try and get a sidebar to scroll if there's too much content in it. However, I'm finding the text overflows the div (as expected because it's a fixed height) but the scroll bar doesn't appear! So it's just flowing on to the page and past the footer. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]
Does anyone know what could be causing this? The code I am using is at: http://pastebin.ca/2627843

The key bits (I think) are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
                $('.nano').nanoScroller();
        });
</script>
```

And:

```
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
}


/* Scrolling */

.nano {
        background: #bba;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
}

.nano .content {
        padding: 10px;
}

.nano .pane   {
        background: #888;
}

.nano .slider {
        background: #111;
}
```

Any comments appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following type of markup structure is needed to make the plugin work:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="nano">


 <div class="content"> 

 ... content here ...  


 </div> 


</div>
```

And,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sidebar').nanoScroller({ scroll: 'top' });
    });
```

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axSUs/)

and css like here,

```
.nano { width: 500px; height: 500px; }
.nano .content { padding: 10px; }
.nano .pane   { background: #888; }
.nano .slider { background: #111; }
```